# Debian can't boot completely; how do I make it start Gnome?

Tags: boot, debian, gdm

I've recently bought a Lenovo Ideapad 5 15ARE05. It comes with Windows pre-installed, but even though I need the Windows, I prefer to work with the Debian operating system.

Thus, I freed some disk space within the Windows partition manager in order to install Linux on it. I followed the steps of the graphical installation of a DVD boot image, since the 15ARE05 does not have an internet plug, and I didn't get the wireless internet to work.

After the installation was finished, the bootloader GRUB worked perfectly fine. But upon selecting Debian as the boot option (as opposed to Windows, which at least does boot), it shows some text about what is loading, which scrolls down rapidly as new things are being loaded, and then, when one expects the GNOME interface to start, it suddenly crashes to a black screen with only a blinking underscore.

I am able to start the command line within the recovery mode.

<s>As I'm typing these lines, I realise that I could try to start it by hand from there. I'll report the results shortly, editing this question.</s>

EDIT: No success. The command "gdm" was not found. Moreover, apt says it can't find a package of this name. Does this mean that it's not installed? But I did run the "big" installation insofar as I used the DVD image on my USB stick.

On the positive side, I seem to be able to mount the USB drive via the command line. I tried to install the wireless internet via cp (file) /lib/firmware, and this did not produce an error, but apt does not seem to be able to access the internet; moreover, it seems as though iwlwifi is not installed either.

Comment: Debian may not have the drivers it needs.  (1) Use Lenovo Update (Start or Control Panel) and update BIOS and all your drivers. Restart and try Debian again. (2) Best way:  Install VMware Workstation and set up a Debian virtual machine. I am on a Windows 10 Host and working in Kali Linux here. Kali has a Debian VM machine base.

Comment: I'm doing the update with the Lenovo tool right now, but I very much dislike the option of using a VM, since I do believe that (a) the Windows running in the background would take away quite some resources (such as CPU computations and RAM) and (b) that Windows may somehow record what I do in the VM.

Comment: Windows does not record what you do in the VM. That does not happen. So long as the machine has adequate resources, CPU load is not an issue either.

Comment: I intend to use the Debian system for resource-consuming mathematical calculations. Both RAM and CPU will be used, and in fact, the speed and accuracy of my computations are directly correlated to the availability of the former. (I've also updated the BIOS, but this has had no effect; I can still only see the blinking underscore when the Gnome user choice is supposed to be displayed.)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the kernel that Debian uses is too old for the given laptop. Therefore, I switched to Mint, which comes with version 5.4 of the Linux kernel.